# Cannot open jvm.options

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm

So I'm new to Elasticsearch (using 5.2.2) and already in the beginning I had troubles installing and configuring the software. I finally managed to run the elasticsearch.bat, but the first line in the console is the following :

**FINDSTR: cannot open 'correct path to jvm.options'**.

I already copied the jvm.options to the root (so elasticsearch/bin), I changed the path to the config map (so ..\config\jvm.options) but still the same result..

Comment: From my understanding `jvm.options` should be in `/config` folder. How are you starting your elastic instance? Usually I'm making sure i'm starting it as `./bin/elasticsearch.sh` from **root** folder, but not from `./bin` folder like `./elasticsearch.sh`.

Comment: Because I've been trying some different solutions, jvm.options is in the /config folder but also in /bin/config. I updated the path twice for each solution but still got the same result. It's not telling me it can't find jvm.options, it's saying that it cannot open it, so perhaps the path is correct but something else is wrong?